# Handling Ruby "failed with.... "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def slicer_imlib2(zoom_level, file_path, output_path)
    begin
      tile_size = 256
      file_path = "public/#{file_path}"

      image = Imlib2::Image.load_image file_path

      image_width = image.width
      image_height = image.height
.....
....
    end
      end
      image = nil
    rescue
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
end
```

The begin rescue blocks don't work

I'm getting

```
[Worker()] UserImage#slice_lib failed with Imlib2::Error::DeletedError: image deleted - 0 failed attempts
[Worker()] UserImage#slice_lib failed with Imlib2::Error::DeletedError: image deleted - 0 failed attempts
[Worker()] UserImage#slice_lib failed with Imlib2::Error::DeletedError: image deleted - 0 failed attempts
[Worker()] 3 jobs processed at 32.5508 j/s, 3 failed ...
```

I'm trying to return false if im getting Imlib2::Error::DeletedError: image deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
begin
  # ...
rescue Imlib2::Error::DeletedError
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

rescue (without specifing an ErrorClass) does only catch StandardErrors (Imlib2::Error::DeletedError directly inherits from Exception).

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about specifying but I was 100% sure that it will catch all errors

Comment: The always catch all approach is to write "rescue Exception", but it's generally not recommended, because it will really catch everything (even SyntaxErrors)

Comment: will rescue Imlib2::Error will catch all errors related to Imlib2 ?

Answer (score 0):

J-_-L gives you a good answer, but i just wanted to say something on the practices side that may save you from some hassle.

In your example, i would not use exceptions. If you want to check whether an image is deleted or not, it's better to use a standard find and handle the return value.

An exception should generally be used NOT to handle user input but look for weird things happening. For instance, a method that expects an argument to be either 1 or 0, suddenly gets 2 as input. That would be a proper exception handling place.

Comment: Image is not deleted, when theres no enough memory to load an image the Imlib2 doesn't say anything until you try to use the variable that points to the image in memory. The library sees that the pointer doesn't point to the image and it prints out "image is deleted" which is the same as if you try to use Imlib2 on a nil variable. I guess that the library should differentiate these exceptions to different types, it took me some time to find out why the "image was deleted".